# What form of conjugate prior best fits this likelihood distribution?

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, posterior, conjugate-prior, logistic-distribution

Joint likelihood of a two part model consisting of logistic regression and log-normal model:[image: ][1][1]]

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typesetting. Images are not searchable.

Comment: @StubbornAtom, thanks for your response, am actually new here, never knew the platform could decode LaTeX script, thanks for the hint. the likelihood distribution has been re-written as below $$L\left( {\beta _1 ,\beta _2 ,\sigma } \right) = \prod\limits_{y_i  = 0} {\left[ {\frac{{e^{x'_{1i} \beta _1 } }}{{1 + e^{x'_{1i} \beta _1 } }}} \right]} \left[ {\prod\limits_{y_i  > 0} {\frac{1}{{1 + e^{x'_{1i} \beta _1 } }}\sigma ^{ - 1} \phi \left( {\frac{{\log (y_i ) - x'_{2i} \beta _2 }}{\sigma }} \right)} } \right]$$

Comment: where $
P(Y_i  > 0) = \frac{1}{{1 + e^{x'_{1i} \beta _1 } }}$ and $P(Y_i  = 0) = \frac{{e^{x'_{1i} \beta _1 } }}{{1 + e^{x'_{1i} \beta _1 } }}$

Comment: So, edit the question, please. Also, providing a bit more information context would help the reader.

Answer (score 1):

For general distributions, a conjugate prior is not guaranteed to exist (though they are if the distribution is from the [exponential family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family)).

Whilst the log-normal distribution is in the exponential family, the logistic distribution is not. So *a priori* I would not assume that a conjugate prior exists.

Having said that - at a glance [this](http://www3.stat.sinica.edu.tw/statistica/oldpdf/A13n212.pdf) paper seems to address conjugate priors for Generalised Linear Models (of which the logistic model is an example).

If you intend to use MCMC to perform inference on the model, then ultimately conjugacy is not important, and you can choose priors relatively freely; [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.398.733&rep=rep1&type=pdf) paper might prove useful if you want to explore this route.

**Update:**
An excellent resource enumerating appropriate priors (and pre-processing steps) for various scenarios has been prepared by the Stan dev community; you can find it [here](https://github.com/stan-dev/stan/wiki/Prior-Choice-Recommendations), and it covers linear and logistic regression.

Comment: thanks, am looking into the papers you recommended, I actually thought in similar fashion concerning the logistic regression, the best to do is to look at more literature and see how the Bayesian scholars have been able to incorporate prior for such distribution, I noticed that Normal distribution is quite common based on the papers have reviewed e.g. https://www4.stat.ncsu.edu/~reich/ABA/code/GLM . As for the log-normal distribution, a normal distribution is suitable for the covariate parameter and an inverse-gamma distribution for variance-cov parameter.

Comment: I've added one further reference for you to look at, if you're happy to move away from conjugacy. Its effectively a handbook of appropriate priors for various scenarios.